# JS - Check element rendered opacity value

Tags: javascript, css, rendering

Let's say I have the following DOM. The element opacity is 1, but since it is wrapped by a parent div, it will render with opacity 0.1:

```js
let el = document.getElementById("element");
console.log(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el)["opacity"]);
```

```html
<div style="opacity:0.1">
  <div id="element">Check Me</div>
</div>
```

The result is still 1.

I thought of looping through the element's hierarchy and check to see if somewhere in the chain an ancestor have a different opacity and save the minimum value, but I'm thinking that there got to be an easier way.

How can I get the rendered opacity value?

Comment: I don't think there is an easier way.You want to get the opacity you see while the opacity isn't belong to any element.So,you can't get it directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I thought of looping through the element's hierarchy...and save the minimum value

It's worse than that. :-) If ancestors have opacity, the values are combined (I believe they're multiplied together), note how the second one is lighter than the first:

```html
<div style="opacity:0.3">
  <div>Check Me</div>
</div>
<div style="opacity:0.3">
  <div style="opacity:0.5">
    <div>Check Me</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I think you have to go through the hierarchy and multiply the values toether:

```js
let element = document.getElementById("element");
let opacity = 1;
while (element && element.nodeType === 1) {
  const op = getComputedStyle(element).opacity;
  if (op) {
    opacity *= parseFloat(op);
  }
  element = element.parentNode;
}
console.log("Effective opacity: ", opacity);
```

```html
<div style="opacity:0.1">
  <div>Check Me - for comparison with the one below</div>
</div>
<div style="opacity:0.2">
  <div style="opacity:0.5">
    <div id="element">Check Me</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, That's what I thought :(